# Getting user input data on click of a button

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm new to Angular and I am creating a simple to do list app. I want the description, start time and end time that the user inputs to be added to an array as an object when the user clicks the button.

I am able to get the user input when just saving it to property like this:

Typescript:

```
export class UsersInputComponent {
  descInput: string;
  startInput: number;
  endInput: number;


getUserInput() {
  console.log(this.descInput);
}; // THIS CORRECTLY LOGS THE VALUE WHICH THE USER INPUTS (SEE HTML CODE BELOW)
```

But when I try to create an object with the input values as properties and then push this to an array, like this....

Typescript:

```
export class UsersInputComponent {
  descInput: string;
  startInput: number;
  endInput: number;

  list = [];


  itemDetails = {
    desc: this.descInput,
    start: this.startInput,
    end: this.endInput
};


getUserInput() {
  this.list.push(this.itemDetails)
  console.log(this.list);
}; // THIS LOGS AN ARRAY TO THE CONSOLE WITH 1 OBJECT IN, BUT THE PROPERTIES OF THE OBJECT ALL SHOW AS UNDEFINED
```

The values are undefined when logging to the console. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Here is the html:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 text-center users-input">
        <input class="desc" placeholder="What do you need to do?" type="text" [(ngModel)]="descInput">
        <input class="start" placeholder="Start" type="number" [(ngModel)]="startInput">
        <input class="end" placeholder="End" type="number" [(ngModel)]="endInput">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="getUserInput()">Add Item</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please provide a StackBlitz sample for the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your `ngModel`s are binded to other class members, not to `itemDetails`. You either need to change `ngModel`s to following `[(ngModel)]="itemDetails.desc"` or you can do following when you push to array

```js
getUserInput() {
  this.list.push({
    desc: this.descInput,
    start: this.startInput,
    end: this.endInput
  });
  console.log(this.list);
};
```

Comment: Thank you Bunyamin, this resolved my issue! This does confuse me slightly though as I thought I was simply assigning the value of this.descInput (which is value I get from the ngModel binding) to 'desc'. Would you be kind enough to explain in more detail why this doesn't work?

Comment: It's because, you assign initial values of your `ngModel`s to `itemDetails`. After then, you never update it. When user interacts with the inputs, `this.descInput`, `this.startInput` and `this.endInput` are indeed getting updated but not `itemDetails`.